# Pattern for initializing unknown subclass

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I am trying to make a function f that works like this:

```
StorageObject::addItem (const AbstractBase& base) {
    AbstractBase* storage = new Derived1(base);
}
```

However, I would like f to work with classes Derived2, Derived3 etc as well. Is there a way to get f to call the correct constructor depending on the specific subclass of AbstractBase passed to it, without using typecodes?

To put the question in context, I am using this function to initialize a list of objects in a class. While I could do something like

```
Derived1* temp = new Derived1();
storageobject.addItem(*temp);
delete temp;
```

I would prefer to do things like

```
storageobject.addItem(Derived1());
```

and have storageobject handle everything.

Comment: why don't you store references in storageobject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you implement a virtual copy method?

```
AbstractBase* storage = base.Copy()
```

By the way, this is quite C++ specific, because using C# it could be simply implemented by reflection.

```
Activiator.CreateInstance(temp.GetType(), temp);
```

Of course, there are some nice factory patterns around, but this really depends on the concrete problem you need to solve.

Comment: +1. The "Copy" method is  the prototype pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern

Answer (score 0):

- If you can use templates.
- If you have not templates in language - use abstract factory pattern